# Which of the following images is the correct logo depicted in the Witcher games?

Tags: the-witcher

[image] [image]

I'm a little confused if both of these images represent the correct logo used in the Witcher games.

If neither, then what *is* the correct version that was used in the games?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [the computer games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witcher_(video_game_series)) Geralt wears a [wolf medallion](https://witcher-games.fandom.com/wiki/Witcher_medallion) that is different from the ones depicted above, with a wolf's head facing directly outwards.

[image]

**The Witcher**
[image]

The Witcher 2
[image]

The Witcher 3
[image]

The designs depicted in your question are the wolf medallion that was [made specifically for Geralt in the Netflix TV show](https://www.ign.com/articles/2019/07/01/netflixs-the-witcher-medallions-explained-see-geralt-ciri-and-yennefers-symbols).

[image]

The uppermost medallion is a mish-mash of Yennefer's obsidian star, Ciri's swallow and Geralt's wolf.

[image]

[image]